# manage.py syncbd not syncing django.contrib apps

Tags: django, django-syncdb, django-contrib

This is probably a setting error somewhere. I have a django app that works fine on my desktop with the developer server and sqlite3.

I upload it to my server and syncdb and it only syncs my custom apps to my database, not the django.contrib apps.

My apache config:

```
ServerRoot "/home/myusername/webapps/accounting/apache2"

LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

KeepAlive Off
Listen 40959
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/myusername/logs/user/access_accounting.log combined
ErrorLog /home/myusername/logs/user/error_accounting.log
ServerLimit 2

<Location "/">
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    PythonPath "['/home/myusername/webapps/accounting', '/home/myusername/webapps/accounting/money', '/home/myusername/webapps/accounting/lib/python2.5', '/home/myusername/webapps/accounting/lib/python2.5/django'] + sys.path"
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE money.settings
    SetHandler python-program
</Location>
```

I have them in my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'money.accounting',
)
```

I don't get any errors when I sync. It just sinks my money.accounting app just like normal.

And I am able to get to the admin section login page, so It's finding some of the django files.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Hailey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the tables are not already present? Remember `syncdb` doesn't alter existing tables once they've been created. What happens if you start from a completely empty database?

If that doesn't help, are you certain that the settings file is referring to the database you think it is?